# How to Save Choice Field to Sharepoint List in a webpart?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, checkboxlist, multiple-choice, choicefield

I have a SharepointList

List Name:`RegionList`
Fields: `regId number`
        `Regname Choice`**(CheckBox: with Allow Multiple Selection)**

The Choice field items are displayed in CheckBoxList items.
I am saving these items as string with Comma Separated Values.

```
protected string GetSelectedRegions()
        {
            List<String> regList = new List<string>();
            // Loop through each item.
            foreach (ListItem item in chkRegion.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected)
                {
                    // If the item is selected, add the value to the list.
                    regList.Add(item.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Item is not selected, do something else.
                }
            }

            String regs = String.Join(",", regList.ToArray());
            return regs;
        }
```

From above code the `regs` parameter has number of selected items and saved to List.
Now, Problem is when i open the list and open record in `Edit` Mode then `CHOICE Field Doesn't Show any Selected ITEM. But, when i send only single value then it Show the Selected Item that was saved.`

Any Idea?
**Plz let me know how to store the CheckBoxList items to CHOICE Field and Retrive it.** Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for set multi-Checkbox you should use [SPFieldMultiChoiceValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldmultichoicevalue.aspx) like this:

```
protected SPFieldMultiChoiceValue GetSelectedRegions()
     {
        SPFieldMultiChoiceValue multiValue = new SPFieldMultiChoiceValue();

         List<String> regList = new List<string>();
        // Loop through each item.
        foreach (ListItem item in chkRegion.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected)
            {
                // If the item is selected, add the value to the list.
                multiValue.Add(item.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                // Item is not selected, do something else.
            }
        }

        //String regs = String.Join(",", regList.ToArray());
        return multiValue;
    }
```

than set your `SPFieldMultiChoiceValue` to your SPListItem

```
  item["multivalued choice field name"]= GetSelectedRegions();
```